# How to create Laravel api route endpoint/query parameters?

Tags: laravel, rest, laravel-5

I would like to be able to filter the json response using some fields in the database e.g. api/v1/user?username=mary but don't know how to do this.  My second question is that the route api/v1/user/3 is working but I can't remember how I set this up as I did it some time ago. Can anyone help?

api.php

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
Route::apiResource('/user', 'UserController');
});
```

user resource

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
                return parent::toArray($request); 
    }
```

user controller

```
public function show(User $user): UserResource
    {
        return new UserResource ($user);
    }

 public function index(): UserResourceCollection
    {
            return new UserResourceCollection(User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
        ->paginate(5)

    );

    }

 public function store(Request $Request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required',
            'last_name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = User::create($request->all());

        \Mail::to($user)->send(new Welcome);
        return new UserResourse($user);
    }


public function update(User $user, Request $request): UserResource
    {
        $user->update($request->all());
        return new UserResource($User);
    }

public function destroy(User $user)
    {
        $user->delete();
        return response()->json();
    }

}
```

UPDATED

I have seen several tutorials with the advice that the user has given below but I don't know how to put it together because I already have a show method above.  I tried commenting out the show method and creating another show method for the query string

```
public function show(User $user): UserResourceCollection
    {
       $request->input('username'); 
       return new UserResourceCollection(User::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
       ->where('username', '=', $username)
        ->paginate(2)

    );

    }
```

and added a GET route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function () {
Route::apiResource('/user', 'UserController');

Route::get('/user/{username?}','UserController@show');
});
```

This is working as an endpoint. The pagination part is working I made it smaller so I know it's calling the method but it is searching by id and i want to search by username. Ideally I want to use a query parameter like api/v1/user?username=mary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to create api url parameters.  I started again using this tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3YPhYwcbBM.

This way means I always have to know the id (search by product id rather than filtering reviews by query search) which isn't ideal

e.g. http://localhost:8000/api/v1/products/2/reviews

however I can add more endpoints in place of reviews like categories etc.

Answer (score 0):

To get json request, you can call `$request->input('name')` for example.

You can setup the resource action on controller. By example, you can create `UserController.show` method. So, the `GET /user/{id}` method will be handled by `UserController.show`

For more example, you read [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

Comment: Thank you.  I think that answers my second question.  Do you know what file this method will be in I can't see it.

Comment: Oh, sorry if I'm not clearly answer you question. First, you can get the json value by using this example `$request->input('name')`

For second question,  the method, you can create on your `UserController.php`

Comment: Sorry I am new to Laravel I understand however I don't know how to put it all together.  I have edited my question above with what I have tried